# How to get the value of MSB bit of a token returned by LEX

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I have a lex specification file as below;
 if the input is of the form R[0-7] it will return a token "REG" to yacc file.
Now I want to do "Rotate right with carry" operation in lex and yacc.
so to do that I need to know the value of R1[7] and R1[0] so that I can use:

```
         R1[0] = CF
         CF = R1[7]
```

In my yacc file, all the register values are stored in regmem.
Now how do I define the number of bits for register and how do I access them?

Comment: mmm... yacc is a parser generator. At parser time we check the syntax, we don't implement the semantic. You need to add the relevant C code to what yacc generates.

Comment: Yes I have written c code , but Iam not understanding how to take the bit value of register. For just say rotate right; I have RR REG  {$$ = regmem[$2]= regmem[$2] << 1;}  this is working fine. But How do I go for RRC REG... By RRC I mean "Rotate right with carry"

Comment: As a wild guess I'd say something like `RR REG {$$ = regmem[$2] = regmem[$2] >> 7 | regmem[$2] << 1 ;}` but I don't know.

Comment: Yeah something like that. But I need to trace the individual bit. Like for conditional jump instructions I need to know the status of Carry Flag. for example  - in verilog coding I can declare R1[7:0] as reg and I can easily trace the value of individual bit ( R1[0] or R1[7] like that). But how do we do it in yacc or c??

Comment: With ANDs: `regmem[$2] & 0x40` is non zero if *bit6* is set (note: 2^6 = 64 = 0x40). If you want to extract the n-th bit use `(regmem[$2] & (1 << n)) >> n` though usually it is an overkill.

Comment: Thank you very much!  So I need to do some arrangements like you said. Is there any possibility of declaring 8 bit unsigned value. I want to define a Status register of 8 bit, 0th bit will be Carry Flag and 1st bit will be Overflow flag and so on..